# API Laravel through Java application

Tags: java, php, laravel-5.1, csrf

I have a `LARAVEL API` coded in `PHP` with `MYSQL Database` but i want to create a Desktop App for few users, but for this i have to call my API with token csrf how can i do that

I tried like that

(It is a test class)

```
    package com.trying.text;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

import javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection;

public class Main {
    private final static String USER_AGENT = "Mozilla/5.0";
    private static String csrf;
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        System.out.println("Testing 1 - Send Http GET request");
        sendGet();
        System.out.println("Testing 2 - Send Http POST request");
        sendPost();

    }

    public static void connectionHttp(){

    }

    // HTTP GET request
        private static void sendGet() throws Exception {

            String url = "http://xxx.xxx.com/api/documents/41/reglements";

            URL obj = new URL(url);
            HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();

            // optional default is GET
            con.setRequestMethod("GET");

            //add request header
            con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", USER_AGENT);

            int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
            System.out.println("\nSending 'GET' request to URL : " + url);
            System.out.println("Response Code : " + responseCode);

            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
            String inputLine;
            StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

            while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                response.append(inputLine);
            }
            in.close();

            // strip out your required data with a regex
            Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(".*<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"_token\" value=\"(.*?)\">.*");
            Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(response.toString());

            if (matcher.find()) {
                System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
                csrf = matcher.group(1);
                sendPost();
            }
            //print result
            System.out.println(response.toString());

        }

        // HTTP POST request
        private static void sendPost() throws Exception {

            String url = "http://xxx.xxx.com/login";
            URL obj = new URL(url);
            HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();

            //add reuqest header
            con.setRequestMethod("POST");
            con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", USER_AGENT);
            con.setRequestProperty("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.5");

            String urlParameters = "name=test&password=test&_token=" + csrf;

            // Send post request
            con.setDoOutput(true);
            DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(con.getOutputStream());
            wr.writeBytes(urlParameters);
            wr.flush();
            wr.close();

            int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
            System.out.println("\nSending 'POST' request to URL : " + url);
            System.out.println("Post parameters : " + urlParameters);
            System.out.println("Response Code : " + responseCode);

            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
            String inputLine;
            StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

            while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                response.append(inputLine);
            }
            in.close();

            //print result
            System.out.println(response.toString());

        }
}
```

I succeed to make a get call when  i don't have to give to him a csrf (The first call is route that didn't under web middleware (Laravel for security and more..) But when i need to call an adress that need a csrf i try to get the csrf of one page that i know that had a csrf hidden input but i don't sicced to send a post request.

I have a 500 HTTP response.

Comment: Check laravel logs for details. 500 is a generic server error.

Comment: I know that the error is because that i don't send the good csrf

Comment: You are not sending any cookies, are you? Frankly using csrf tokens for API doesn't make much sense.